# Incorrect height iphone

Tags: javascript, html, css, iphone, mobile

I have a problem when viewing a page in landscape mode on iphones (testing on model SE but it seems like a lot of people have the same problem with other iphones).

I have made an example below, it is a simple webpage with two lines of texts one text in the top and one in the bottom.

The problem is that when i view the page in normal mode everything looks fine, but when rotating the phone in landscape mode the addressbar covers the top and the toolbar covers the bottom of the page. I have added some javascript to scroll the page so that it starts under the address bar, but since the page is now scrolled down the last line is hidden behind the toolbar.

I have tested a lot of meta tags and different css hacks but to no good.

I just want both text to be shown when going to this page, i dont want to have to scroll, but just for info i want to be able to zoom in on the page later on so the solution can't block zoom on the page.

Code:

```
<html>
<meta content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport" />
<script>
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    }, 0);
});
window.addEventListener("resize",function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    }, 0);
});
</script>
<style>
div {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        margin: auto;
}
</style>
<body>
Top
<div>
Bottom
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add [meta viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) like,

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Also read [Using the Viewport](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help but unfortunately it did not change anything. I still only see the top line and the bottom is hidden unless i scroll down the page and then loose the top line.